# What is the best way to store and search within xml in mysql database

Tags: mysql, xml, database

I am using mysql 5.5 and I need to store like 100-200 xml files in the database, each file has 20-30 nodes. Besides, I also need to frequently search data within the xml, what is the best way to do so?

edit: For some reason I have to adhere to mysql, I cant switch to a xml database or something.

Comment: You should probably investigate use of a NoSQL database if you want to be able to query nodes on an arbitrarily structured data document.

Comment: If you have xml files, why do you want to store them in a dataBase? you can just store them in your server.

Comment: @MikeBrant I cant switch to other database.

Comment: @Gwenc37 Yeah, I guess I dont have to. But what is the best way to query nodes within them?

Comment: The [XML functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html) will be the best MySQL can do.

Comment: @VMai I also read this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/), do you think it is a better way than using xml? I can break the xml files into tables.

Comment: You should take a look at Bill Karwins slides to [SQL antipatterns](http://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back), slide 49 and following. Maybe the use of a closure table instead of nested sets would be better. Every XML document would begin at level 2.

Comment: @phil I didn't say anything about switching your database, rather simply putting this use case in a NoSQL store.  Trying to query XML documents stored in relational tables is not an optimized solution.  Using MySQL XML function will not allow for optimized searching using an index, so you best approaches may be to map the XML data to a more reasonable relational structure (which could be painful if the XML structure is arbitrary or changes frequently), y store generated metadata on the XML files in tables for more optimized searching, or simply use a NoSQL store for this information.